# "stack build" failed randomly

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

When I used `stack build` to build a package, it failed randomly during the process of installing dependent packages. Here is an example error message:

`While building package statistics-0.13.3.0 using:
      /home/work/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.24.0.0-ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure (-11)
    Logs have been written to: /home/work/server/dev/taiji/.stack-work/logs/statistics-0.13.3.0.log`

I said "failed randomly" because this can be fixed by restart `stack build`. But it will fail on building another package later.

I looked at the `dmesg | tail`, it says:

`[1029507.778048] ghc[16868]: segfault at 7d538d610628 ip 00007f5384094ed0 sp 00007ffceed0bda0 error 4 in libHSrts_thr-ghc8.0.1.so[7f538407a000+63000]
[1029524.911751] ghc[17599]: segfault at 100206005838 ip 00007f1c727de754 sp 00007ffdc160fd58 error 4 in libHSghc-8.0.1-ghc8.0.1.so[7f1c6e4de000+49c9000]
[1029533.035216] ghc[16789]: segfault at 7da273b664f0 ip 00007fa273b35a8e sp 00007ffe2f55d540 error 4 in libHSrts_thr-ghc8.0.1.so[7fa273b1c000+63000]`

Any idea?

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Nothing. It is empty.

Comment: segfault in GHC suggests a compiler error, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a memory defect issue.